# Tomcat application Profiler for Eclipse indigo

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-plugin, profiling, eclipse-tptp

I tried installing TPTP profiler in eclipse indigo.  However It is not working I am getting the following error.

> Your platform is not supported by Eclipse TPTP.  The Integrated Agent
>   Controller will be disabled.   To profile on a supported host, please
>   install and use a stand-alone Agent Controller on that host.

I dont know how to check my sql memory leaks in my application.  Is there any other Eclipse tool to check for memory leak.  I want to profile my webapplication hosted in Tomcat.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [visualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/profiler.html)
or [mat](http://eclipse.org/mat/)

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Memory Analysis Tool](http://eclipse.org/mat/) (MAT) for this. MAT can  read the memory of a running Java application directly, but it can also read the memory dumps generated by either visualVM or jmap.