# Exception in thread ""http-apr-8080"-exec-43" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space Error

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets, tomcat7

I made a dynamic web project in Eclipse with hibernate frameworks(servlet).
 The first run is ok.
 
But run it for more times, i get this **Exception**

```
Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost, jdk1.7.0_17. 
On Win2007 32 bits with 4GB of RAM
```

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646483/jboss-7-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space The same applies to your case

Comment: While this might well be a duplicate of the given question it could also be the hibernate-issue mentioned in may answer and not be related to tomcat in any way...

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening if you have a low memory allocated for the VM. Increase the memory(PermGen) available for the VM.

http://www.genericarticles.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=How_to_increase_tomcat_memory_inside_eclipse

If you still have an issue after increasing the memory, then attach a profiler and inspect to see if you have any memory leaks.

[Tomcat application Profiler for Eclipse indigo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390584/tomcat-application-profiler-for-eclipse-indigo)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two problems, depending on what you mean with "run it for more times":

- If it is "after multiple deployments" you might have run into menmory-leak with classloading. Tomcat 6 definitely had some trouble with this, don't know for sure about tomcat 7.
- If it is "after multiple invocations" of the same deployed application this could be a bug in your application with handling the `SessionFactory`/`EntityManagerFactory`. As a rule of thumb make sure you only create *one* `SessionFactory`/`EntityManagerFactory` over all the lifetime of your aplpication. Each invocation should only create a `Session`/`EntityManager` from the existing factory.